# На JS при нажатии на кнопку блок появляется и при нажатии на туже кнопку блок исчезал

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой код

```
<button class="s" OnClick="view()">S</button>

<script>
        function view(){
            document.getElementById("pusks").style.display = "block";
        };
</script>
```

Всё работает, блок появляется, но как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на туже кнопку, он снова пропадал?

Comment: `document.getElementById("pusks").classList.toggle("invis");` и CSS → `.invis { display: none; }`

Comment: Вынесите состояние этого элемента в переменную вне функции что-то вроде let showEl = false; а в функции при заходе в  нее смотрите значение этой переменной и показываете/скрываете элемент, и меняете значение этой переменной на противоположное.

Comment: invis в данном случае на кнопку лепится?

Comment: На элемент `id="pusks" class="invis"`

Comment: Спасибо всем, помогло.